# How to install sudo and mpicc in windows?

Tags: c#, cmd, sudo, openmpi, mpich

I want to run a mpicc code written in C#. But to run the same I'll have to install `sudo apt install mpich` and to do that I need `sudo` command in windows cmd window. I tried using git bash and installed gsudo but didn't work. Is there any other way to run my file?

Commands to use to run my file:

```
mpicc p_mpi.c -o p_mpi
mpirun -np 4 ./p_mpi
```

Commands I used before using the above and failed:

```
sudo apt install mpich
winget install gsudo
gsudo apt install mpich
```

Comment: It would be perhaps a good idea to visit the [MPICH homepage](https://www.mpich.org/), click in menu __Documentation__ on the menu item [Guides](https://www.mpich.org/documentation/guides/). The opened (or downloaded) PDF file does not contain the word __Windows__ on any of the 16 pages. There is also on the MPICH homepage a __Search__ box and entering there __Windows__ returns just a list with four page references, three from 2012 and one from 2011. So what has you let think this source code package is coded for usage on Windows with C#?

Comment: The MPICH homepage has in menu __Support__ also the menu item [FAQs](https://wiki.mpich.org/mpich/index.php/Frequently_Asked_Questions). The Frequently Asked Questions page contains [1.5 Q: Why can't I build MPICH on Windows anymore?](https://wiki.mpich.org/mpich/index.php/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Q:_Why_can.27t_I_build_MPICH_on_Windows_anymore.3F)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**sudo** is a linux command for running a program as administrator. It can not be used in windows.

If you are using windows but need to use linux only programs i sugest trying out [wsl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install).

**apt** is also a program that does not work in windows. It is a program used for installing and updating programs in debian based linux distributions.

Comment: The wsl feature worked. Thanks :)